# Is it possible to edit this html file without root?

Tags: html, apache, server

my professor gave us a challenge: to edit this page http://teste.ads.cnecsan.edu.br.

It is located on the server on /var/www/teste/index.html

BUT I can't sudo and the file is locked. My groups are root and adm

```
-r--r--r--  1 root     www-data  108 jun 11 10:23 index.html
```

Is there a way to edit or redirect it using some Apache magic or something? Or he is just screwing with us?

Thanks

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory containing the file?  Do you have shell access to the server?  Can you edit Apache configuration?  Can you create .htaccess (or edit an existing one) in the directory where index.html resides?  Since you are in group root, have you tried `chmod` on that file?  There are ways to do it, but your question lacks a *LOT* of information.

Comment: I have shell acces. The awser to those other questions are no. I am on the root group, but I can't sudo or use any "ch" command. The attributes on this file are 'i' and 'e'. The permissions of the folder are drwsrwsr-x  2 www-data  www-data

Comment: There are many other things that can be checked.  I would look at this: 1) Apache configuration, the conf files, .htaccess, ...  2) the user permissions and rights, file, directories, ...  3) sudo rights?  Can you swith to user www-data in any way?  4) ...  The problem is that this comes with intuition and going over the system to find something, but remotely it's hard.  Is there a solution of is your teacher looking for hackers? :-)